# Client display resolution detection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, resolution

Currently I'm using following PHP+JavaScript code to detect clients browser windows size

```
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(isSet($_GET['w']) && isSet($_GET['h']))
{
$w = $_GET['w']; 
$h = $_GET['h'];
}


if(!$w && !$h)
{
    $pos= strpos($url, '?');
    if($pos===false)
    {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo "var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
window.location.href = '".$url."?w='+w+'&h='+h;
</script>'";
}

else {
echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo "var w = screen.width;
var h = screen.height;
window.location.href =  '".$url."&w='+w+'&h='+h;
</script>'";
}
}
```

I wonder, is there any way to optimize code (post via ajax, .. etc) or easy way to do it?

Comment: What's your purpose of this? It might not be necessary at all. It sounds like you're using this to specify which CSS data to send (based on a comment below), but a single CSS file can handle multiple drastically different resolutions, so that really wouldn't be necessary (and would work for clients with JS disabled, and eliminate a round trip). If it's for analytics, you could just send an AJAX request on every page load with the w/h (or however frequently you desire, such as new sessions only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really as you have to do a round trip to the broser first to determine the screensize.

If you need the screensize for subsequent request only, you could do an ajax call and save the values in the session (jquery example):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var w = screen.width;
  var h = screen.height;
  $.load('/yourPhpScriptToSaveTheSession.php?&w='+w+'&h='+h);
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with js, is there any way to echo `var w`, or `var h`? i mean something like that `<?=$var?>` (like in php). In my case i want to send them to `css.php`. in php it looks like that `<link rel="stylesheet" href="core/design/css.php?w=<?=$w?>&h=<?=$h?>" type="text/css" media="all">`

Comment: Yes, you can do something like: `var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
var cssNode = document.createElement('link');
cssNode.type = 'text/css';
cssNode.rel = 'stylesheet';
cssNode.href = 'core/design/css.php?w=' + w + '&h=' + h;
cssNode.media = 'screen';
headID.appendChild(cssNode);`  BUT BE AWARE: visitors with Javascript disabled will so no styles at all..

Answer (score 0):

here without ajax

```
if ( $_GET["setscreen"] ) $_SESSION['display_resolution'] = $_GET['screenwidth'] . 'x' . $_GET['screenheight'];
if ( $_GET["setscreen"] ) header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if ( ! $_SESSION['display_resolution'] ) echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?setscreen=1&screenwidth="+screen.width+"&screenheight="+screen.height;</script>';
```

the session display_resolution contains a string similar to: 1280 x 1024